Gitignore asterisk "*" and slashes
According to the gitignore documentation, an asterisk * matches anything except a slash. It's not clear to me how that actually works in practice.
Consider the following structure for example:
foo/
foo/test_dir1/test_file1
foo/test_dir1/test_dir2/test_file2
foo/test_dir1/test_dir2/test_dir3/test_file3

All three files are ignored with the gitignore directive: /foo/test_dir1/*
So clearly the two slashes in test_dir1/test_dir2/test_dir3 are ignored.
It makes sense if you consider that /foo/test_dir1/* matches with /foo/test_dir1/test_dir2, and therefore anything in this directory will be ignored. However I am struggling to understand in what case a slash would indeed be ignored and what would be the practicality of that.
I would have expected test_file2 and test_file3 to not be ignored with the example above.

"............" is very unclear in a structure.

If you had test_file2 in both /foo/test_dir1/test_dir2 and /foo/test_dir1/test_dir2/test_dir3, then I suppose /foo/test_dir1/*/test_file2 would ignore the one in test_dir2, and not that one in test_dir3, because * can only match test_dir2, because can't match the slash to match the test_dir2/test_dir3

Sorry I was struggling to format the post...

it test_dir2 a subdirectory of test_dir1, or not .....

yes the directories are nested

Why would you have expected those files to not be ignored when the git ignore docs explicitly tell you they will be? If ignoring a directory means anything it means not looking at its contents. If you want directories to not be ignored add !*/ to the end of your .gitignores.

@jthill the doc says that * will not match with a slash, which I interpreted as foo/test_dir1/test_dir2/ is not a match because of the trailing slash, therefore anything under it would not be ignored.

Except that pattern is never even tested, because you told Git not to bother.

* also matches directories, and if a directory is ignored, git will completely ignore its content. In your case: this means that test_dir2 is ignored, so test_file2, test_dir3/ and test_dir3/test_file3 are not even inspected. This is part of the implementation, I agree the documentation could be worded differently to highlight this more clearly.

@jthill Thank you for your replies, but the last example in the doc is clearly violated then: "The pattern foo/*, matches foo/test.json (a regular file), foo/bar (a directory), but it does not match foo/bar/hello.c (a regular file), as the asterisk in the pattern does not match bar/hello.c which has a slash in it." Therefore I would have expected foo/test_dir1/test_dir2/test_file2 to not be matched for the exact same reason. That example is wrong then?

@LeGEC Doesn't your explanation contradict the example in the doc with foo/bar/hello.c? Thanks!

Blindspotting comes for us all, I've been there, so I say this with more sympathy than  may be apparent: you really need to take a step back here, take a walk or get some sleep or something. You told Git to ignore foo/test_dir1/*, which matches foo/test_dir1/test_dir2,  and no later pattern rescinds that order, so that entire directory is ignored. When Git encounters that directory while scanning the filesystem for things to add, it ignores that directory. It doesn't look there at all. It never even looks at anything inside that directory. Exactly as per your instructions.

@jthill I understand that and even wrote the same thing in my original post. That being said the example in the documentation with foo/bar/hello.c is incorrect then. Please excuse that my original expectations were aligned with this example provided in the doc itself!

The example is perfectly correct. The pattern would not match if it was ever checked against a file you correctly think should not match it. The issue isn't what the pattern would or would not or should or should not match, the issue is that you told Git not to ever match that path you're mad about against anything at all, to summarily ignore it anything in its subdir without checking. So far as Git's concerned the contents of test_dir2 do not exist. Your complaint is as wildly off base as if you'd deleted the files, as if that would somehow make the example wrong instead of what you're doing.

TL;DR: in order to have insight on why a file or directory is ignored in your repo, run:
git check-ignore -v path/to/file_or_directory


Your main issue seems to reconcile the pattern matching rules described by the documentation with the fact that some content gets ignored, even though the documentation states that they don't match a pattern.
Here is the gotcha:

the documenation describes how an individual file or directory can be matched,
however, it does not describe very precisely what are the implications of being a match

One very important effect of being matched:

if, after applying all patterns (both inclusive and exclusive patterns), a directory is matched, then all of its content will be ignored -- git will not even list the directory's content for new files


Going back to the example you quote (link, and by re-reading it I find it is misleading):


The pattern foo/*, matches foo/test.json (a regular file), foo/bar (a directory), but it does not match foo/bar/hello.c (a regular file), as the asterisk in the pattern does not match bar/hello.c which has a slash in it.


the misleading part: it doesn't say that, unless other patterns are added to explicitly include foo/bar, since foo/bar is a match, all of foo/bar/ content will be ignored anyways.

Let's look at another illustration of the difference between "being matched" and "being ignored":
# .gitignore:
foo/
!foo/bar

You could expect that the above gitignore file would allow you to ignore all of foo/'s content, except for bar.
If you try it however, you will see that bar is actually ignored:
$ cat .gitignore
foo/
!foo/bar
$ git check-ignore -v foo/bar
.gitignore:1:foo/   foo/bar

Since pattern foo/ matches directory foo/, git will not even run ls inside foo/ to check if some files should be included after all.
Here is a variation that allows to have "ignore everything in foo/ except bar":
$ cat .gitignore
foo/*
!foo/bar
$ git check-ignore -v foo/bar
.gitignore:2:!foo/bar   foo/bar

If you read carefully how files or directories are matched, you will see that :

foo/ is not a match for foo/*,
everything inside foo/ is a match,
but this time, the !foo/bar pattern will also trigger.

The documentation actually explains that (or tries to ?) with its very last example (same link, scroll to bottom):

Example to exclude everything except a specific directory foo/bar (note the /* - without the slash, the wildcard would also exclude everything within foo/bar):
$ cat .gitignore
# exclude everything except directory foo/bar
/*
!/foo
/foo/*
!/foo/bar



Thank you for the in-depth response, really appreciate it!

It applies pattern matching based on the string you are providing. So if you look for foo/*/bar you will find any folders in a structure that start with foo, and end with bar. The slashes are just part of the pattern it looks for and is ignored when it comes as a symbol on it's own. The documentation refers to that.

That's true of pathspecs on the command line, where that behavior's usually more helpful, but not of gitignore patterns, where the more usual fnmatch rules are used because they're more precise.
